# how to vue router use dynamic params require match?

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

I defined a dynamic parameter in my router. This parameter receives certain parameter values ​​even if it is dynamic.

example:

```
{
  path: '/:type',
  component: List,
}
```

There are 2 or 3 parameters that the router can take. for example, the parameters it can take are 'actual' and 'archive'

I want to redirect to 404 when the user types a parameter other than '://localhost:8080/**actual**' or '://localhost:8080/**archive**'. I can do this in the .vue file, but I want to make adjustments in the router file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a [Per-Route Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) on the route configuration itself

```
{
  path: '/:type',
  component: List,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    //check the params
    if(to.params.type === 'actual' ||to.params.type === 'archive'){
      next();
    }else{
      next('/404');//error route
    }
  }
}
```